# How to add data in firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating car park app and i want users to enter some information in edit texts before registering. The edit texts are as follows:

`First Name`, `Last Name`, `Email`, `password`, `car no`.

When user hits register button, i want to store these values in firebase database connected to my project.I want to know how to create tables in firebase and how these values will be stored. I am new to programming.

Answer (score 1):

First retrieve the edittexts:

```
  String email = textEmail.getText().toString().trim();
  String firstname = firstName.getText().toString().trim();
  //etc
```

first authenticate the user using `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` and then add to the database:

```
 private DatabaseReference mDatabase, newUser;
 private FirebaseUser mCurrentUser;
 mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
 auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(SignUpActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            Toasty.info(getApplicationContext(), "creation of account was: " + task.isSuccessful(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toasty.error(getApplicationContext(), "Authentication failed: " + task.getException().getMessage(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                 mCurrentUser= task.getResult().getUser();<-- gets you the uid
                                newUser=mDatabase.child(mCurrentUser.getUid());


                                            newUser.child("email").setValue(email);
                                            newUser.child("firstname").setValue(name);



                                        }
                                    });
```

you will have the following database:

```
users
  userid
    email:userx@gmail.com <--example
    firstname:userx <--example
```

Comment: well you suppose he has the user registered, are you sure this is a good idea?

Comment: What do you mean? first he needs to register the email/password of the user in firebase authentication then if task is successful he sends that data to the database @balsick

Comment: sure, but neither he or you did this @Peter Haddad

Comment: no, but you are not answering his question. He does not in any way suppose or know that such FirebaseAuth exists

Comment: I'm just saying that if he designed a database based authentication maybe the best answer should focus on making the system work like he wants and in the end suggest to move to something more appropriate 

Comment: he just wants database, but I added authentication and database, is the answer good enough now?

Comment: yes man, even too much of an effort from you  maybe he should study by himself a little more

Answer (score 0):

Firebase doesn't store data in tables, it is not a classic database. It's just a big JSON file that might be replicated in several nodes and might span several of them too.

The classic approach is to have the first level children of the root be what you imagine would be the tables. So, for example, you will have

```
{
"users": {
    ...
    }
 }
```

Second, what you are trying to do is very simple and you can know how to do it by opening the starting guide.

Moreover, the best approach to handle users' authentication is not this but using FirebaseAuth. In the guide you'll find about this too.