# How to retrieve multiple data from firebase and display it in text views?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to display user information inside a fragment in app for which i need to retrieve data from firebase.I have also created a seperate UserInformation java class to retrieve data.

```
public class UserInformation {
private String username;
private String email;
private String password;
private String phoneno;
private String carplateno;

public UserInformation() {
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getPhoneno() {
    return phoneno;
}

public void setPhoneno(String phoneno) {
    this.phoneno = phoneno;
}

public String getCarplateno() {
    return carplateno;
}

public void setCarplateno(String carplateno) {
    this.carplateno = carplateno;
}
}
```

Below is my java code in which i have used addEventListener. Kindly tell me how can i extract data and display it in textviews.

```
public class MyProfile extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_profile, null);
    final TextView t1=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Usernametv);
    final TextView t2=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.EmailIdtv);
    final TextView t3=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Passwordtv);
    final TextView t4=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.MobileNumbertv );
    final TextView t5=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.CarPlatetv);

    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    final DatabaseReference table_user = database.getReference("User");


    table_user.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                UserInformation uinfo = new UserInformation();


            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    return v;


}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did the answer help you?

Comment: Nope, it doesnt show anything on the textviews, the text view just disappears when i run the code

Comment: you need to add the settext inside onDataChange

Comment: can you show me the format please

Comment: inside ondatachange write `t2.setText(email);`

Comment: I have used settext and it retrieves and displays information. But when i login with different user, it gives me info of previous user. I want to display information of user that is currently logged in. Do i need to use auth?

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49391801/how-to-add-data-in-firebase-database answer for your question couple of days ago and use that database. You need to get the userid to be able to then get the information of the currently logged in user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167469/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-sarahtech).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
final DatabaseReference table_user = database.getReference("User");


table_user.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
           String plate = ds.child("carPlateNo").getValue().toString();
           String email = ds.child("email").getValue().toString();
               //etc
        }
    }
```

This way you retrieve each value alone, after iterating inside child `sarah` using `for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){`

Comment: can I do setText here itself? t1.setText(plate);